# content property is not working correctly

Tags: css

I'm using css content property but it is not working as expected.

```
content: "\f104";
```

should display `<` but all my content properties are showing a square character.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?  If so, why not ask it; be sure to include sample source so we have some clue as to what precisely the problem is.

Comment: What font are you using? Not all font sets contain all extended characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation `"\f104"` denotes, by definition, the Unicode code point U+F104, which is in the Private Use Area. This means that no character is assigned to the code point in the Unicode standard, and it has a meaning only by private agreements. Therefore, Private Use code points should not be used in public information interchange, e.g. on web pages.

Some font trickeries are known to use Private Code points for various glyphs, often specialized icons. On web pages, they work (when they work) only via `@font-face` definitions that make use of the specific font. When they do not work, browsers typically render a generic symbol of an unrepresentable or unknown character, such as a small rectangle.

To use the character “<” (LESS-THAN SIGN) in the `content` attribute, it is simplest to write it as such:

```
content: "<";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to include font awesome css 
http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/ 
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/
I was just copying something done in another website and now it is working thank u all

Comment: For me i had the font working, but there was a font-family rule for * set to important which was conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

You need use this construction in CSS for example:

```
.yourclass:before {
     content: '\f104';
     display: inline-block;
     font: 14px/1 FontAwesome;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-size: inherit;
     text-rendering: auto;
}
```

Before using this code "Awesome Font" in  is required!